# How is the concept of multivariable differentiability useful?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I recently studied about how to differentiate multivariable functions $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$.
$$ \lim_{x\to a}\frac{\|F(x)-F(a)-J(x-a)\|}{\|x-a\|}=0
$$
After some thinking, I now understand why this is a 'natural' definition for differentiation. But I don't understand why this concept is useful. The main theorems in the chapter I am reading are the inverse function theorem, and the implicit function theorem. But both of these theorems require continuous differentiability. The only place I think I saw that limit used is (I think), to show that there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $a$ such that $f(x)\neq f(a)$ for $a \neq x\in U$, where $\det f'(a)\neq 0 $. So I got to think differentiability  doesn't really have interesting consequences, like in the one-dimensional case.

The definition of differentiable at a point comes out very early in the text, and it seems pretty important. So are there any interesting theorems or properties about differentiable functions, which don't need continuous differentiability? So far I think the chapter about differentiation is mainly there to talk about the two theorems that I mentioned. If the two theorems are what the book wanted to show, than I think a more logical approach would be considering $C^1$ functions from the start and showing that limit as a theorem.

P.S I'm reading Michael Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds.

Comment: The fundamental strategy of calculus is to simplify calculations by replacing a nonlinear function $f$ (difficult) with its local linear approximation $L(x) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x - x_0)$ (which is easy to work with). It is the essential idea of calculus. (I know you want examples and this doesn't answer your question; but I still think it's worth emphasizing that big picture idea.)

Comment: @littleO Well, if it is easy to work with, it seems strange that there are no theorems that can be derived without the additional hypothesis that the function is continuously differentiable.

Comment: Can you define what it means for a function to be continuously differentiable without referring to the limit above?

Comment: @JanBohr Isn't it defined as a function which all partial derivatives are continuous?

Comment: Ah, I see. So you accept the limit definition in one dimension and then define (multivariate) $C^1$ with reference to that. From a logical point of view this is sound. I think it's still worth emphasising an approach which does not refer to the one-dimensional case. E.g. it's not always easiest to prove that a map is $C^1$ by looking at the partial derivatives. Consider for example $f:\mathrm{Gl}(n,\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}, x\mapsto x^{-1}$ and try to prove that it is continuously differentiable; using the limit above is a lot cleaner.

Comment: Further, having the notion of a 'Fréchet-derivative' (limit above) is useful, as it is a strictly stronger notion than the 'Gateaux-derivative' (directional derivatives) when you work on infinite dimensional spaces. So I'd say that starting with said limit has more of a pedagogical or conceptual merit; indeed there might not be many results for functions which are only pointwise differentiable, but not continuously differentiable.

Comment: One example is the chain rule. If $h$ is differentiable at $x$ and $g$ is differentiable at $h(x)$, then $f = g \circ h$ is differentiable at $x$. It would be inelegant to add additional unnecessary assumptions when stating this theorem. The key idea is just local linear approximation.

Comment: @littleO I'm playing the devils' advocate now, but in a world where you only care about continuous differentiability, you'd only be interested in a $C^1$-version of the chain rule, i.e. for $C^1$-functions $g,h$, also $f=g\circ h$ is $C^1$. No?